# How can I set image in background , I put image in background using CSS, but sadly uper curve is shows right but bottom of image is show flat

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```css
.bg-pink{
          background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF8tF.png);
          background-size: cover;
          margin-bottom: 44px;
          background-position: top;
        }
```

```html
<body>
      <!-- Top content -->
      <div class="top-content">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg-pink">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Thank You!</h1>
                    <p class="lead"><strong>Please check your email</strong> for further instructions on how to complete your account setup.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="lead">
                      <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button">Continue</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

I see this type of background image but  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyxrP.png)

I want 2nd one shape like bottom [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF8tF.png)

I Use this HTML and CSS ... Please check images , I also try with background-size: cover; and Min-height and padding but I m not getting bottom shape.

Comment: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show your css and html.
try: 
`background-size: cover;` 
or 
`min-height: xxxpx;`

Comment: @Bendar nothing happens

Comment: The path should be in single or double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. But I would suggest using a higher resolution image for when it's displayed on high res.

I updated the background-size and background-repeat.

```css
.bg-pink{
    background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF8tF.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin-bottom: 44px;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <!-- Top content -->
      <div class="top-content">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row bg-pink">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                    <h1 class="display-3">Thank You!</h1>
                    <p class="lead"><strong>Please check your email</strong> for further instructions on how to complete your account setup.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p class="lead">
                      <a class="btn btn-success" href="#" role="button">Continue</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
```